# Reload XPPageSelector

Tags: devexpress, xppageselector

I attach XPCollection to XPPageSelector as its collection, if I change the Cretia of XPCollection, How can i make XPPageSelector recalculate PageCount and reload itself using new cretia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is to create a new XPPageSelector.  It is impossible to force the old one to work with the modified XPCollection.

Comment: This is what i am doing, but i have to do a bunch of Databinding manually. :(:(